# If $V_c = \frac{321.8}{225.5}V_k$, and the equation is $V_k + V_c$, how do I get $V_k(1+\frac{321.8}{225.5})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It takes Kim twice as long to run $2,255$ decimeters as it takes Cara to run $1/10$ of a mile. They start $1$ kilometer apart and begin running toward each other. How far, to the nearest meter, will Kim have run when they meet? Assume that $1$ mile = $1.61$ kilometers.

Comment: $V_k+V_c$ is not an equation.  Your title refers to partial results on the problem.  You should explain how they are linked.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question in the title, if you have 
$$V_c=\frac {321.8}{225.5}V_k\\
V_c+V_k=\frac {321.8}{225.5}V_k+V_k=\left(\frac {321.8}{225.5}+1\right)V_k$$
by the distributive principle.